# C# Power Point change Table Cell Fonts at once

Tags: c#, fonts, size, powerpoint

I create a table in Excel and then copy it to Powerpoint. Then I edit the table cell fonts. If you do it interactively you can select the table and set any font size, but using C#, I couldn't do the same thing. Now I'm setting font size of each cell one by one, but if the table is large it is taking a lot of time. Is there any way to set the table font size at once.
Here is the code I'm using now which is very slow:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= rows.Count; i++)
for (int k = 1; k <= cols.Count; k++)
{
    shp.Table.Cell(row, col).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size =  fontSize;
    shp.Table.Cell(row, col).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = fontName;
    shp.Table.Cell(row, col).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Bold = bold;
    shp.Table.Cell(row, col).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = color;
}
```

Comment: Having exactly the same issue, I would love to see a valid answer here. bumping the question. Also: I tried "selecting" the cells and then work on all selected cells at once, as this is what PowerPoint (in its UI) can do, but I'm running into walls achieving this either...

Answer (score -1):

```
shp.Table.Cell(row, col).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size =  8;
shp.Table.Cell(row, col).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Arial (Body)";
shp.Table.Cell(row, col).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Bold = MsoTriState.msoTrue;
int oleColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
shp.Table.Cell(row, col).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = oleColor;
```

Comment: What this answer suppose to do? It just replaced variables by fixed values and does nothing to help to answer the question.

Comment: yes, my variables already contain those values. I just change them dynamically based on slide content. My question was how to set those values in ONE STEP. Right now I am applying those to cells, I want to be able to apply to table in one step